# Unique radio buttons when iterating in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button, form-helpers

I'm creating an application in which I have a list of Symptoms (@all_symptoms) over which I am iterating and I want to have radio buttons for each one indicating whether its presence is true or false. **The problem I keep running up against no matter what I try is that the radio buttons are all named the same, so I can only select true/false once on the entire form.**

I tried changing the label to:

```
<%= ff.radio_button "presence_#{s.id}", true %>
```

but there is an error because there is (obviously) no method called "presence_X" for my symptoms. (For clarity: "presence" *is* an attribute for a Symptom, and it accepts a Boolean value.)

The nested attribute part of the form is because this is part of an Appointment which accepts attributes for Symptoms.

```
<%= f.fields_for :symptoms do |ff| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Presence</th>
    </tr>

    <% @all_symptoms.each do |s| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= s.name %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= ff.label :presence, "True", :value => true %>
        <%= ff.radio_button :presence, true, :value => true %>
        <%= ff.label :presence, "False", :value => false %>
        <%= ff.radio_button :presence, false, :value => false %>
      </td>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<%= ff.radio_button :presence, true, :value => true, name: "presence_#{s.id}" %>
```

Comment: I have tried this. It still only lets me select one radio button for the entire page.

Comment: sorry, radios are associated by it's name, use "name: "presence_#{s.id}" instead of id

Comment: This helped a ton, thanks @arieljuod! It opened up another whole can of worms, but I think I'm moving in the right direction now at least. 
I ended up inspecting the html to reverse-engineer the name it was using, adjusting your response to "name: "visit[symptoms_attributes][#{s.id}][presence]""

(I upvoted, but I don't have a "reputation" so it didn't count.)